# How do you set up SMFPlayer on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming, installation, smoothing, smf

I have been trying to play a simple smooth streaming video following the steps under 
http://smf.codeplex.com/documentation "Building a Windows Phone Player". I have followed the steps exactly and am even using the Big Buck Bunny example. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, the libraries in microsoft-smf-binwp7-2.2012.0605.0.zip from smf.codeplex.com, and Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming v1.1.837.146. I'm debugging on a windows 7 phone (and I have tried release as well), but the video never plays. The view loads, the player controls are visible, no time is set on the player and the play button is visible. I never get a MediaOpened or MediaPluginRegistered event. I have even tried setting AutoLoad and AutoPlay to true and clicking on the play button.

The only exception I get after the Loaded event is the following:
FileNotFoundException
File or assembly name 'System.Windows.debug.resources, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e', or one of its dependencies, was not found.

As a side note, I have tried exactly the same thing on a Windows 8 Phone build to debug on a Windows 8 phone and it works just fine. Please help!